# What is the best approach to check null when object is passed into several layers

Tags: java, oop, methods, nullpointerexception, null

Say I have a method which has the following signature.

```
 public void processData(Map<String,String> map)
```

Now say this method iterates through a list and calls the below method on each of the item in the list, passing the map it has.

```
public void handle(Map<String,String> map)
```

Now I have checked for null in processData method. If its null it doesn't proceed from there, throwing a custom exception. But should I validate the map for null inside handle method too? Because its already validated in processData method. If its null handle method won't be called. I'm having this doubt because handle method has public visibility. I cannot have it as protected or default as both these methods are in classes of different packages. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: It highly depends on the nature of these methods. What does this `handle` do? Imagine that your friends asked you to share this `handle` method with him - should this method accept null? If not, then throw exception. If yes, and this null check is a special case for **your** application, then no.

Comment: What is a Map with only one type?? Did you mean List?

Comment: @Bohemian sorry its a typo. And no I'm not asking for opinions. I am asking for the concrete approach for this. There should be one solid right answer. Please remove the onHold tag. It has upvotes which indicates that members of the community do find it useful.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Thanks for your views. The fact is I know for sure that this won't be called anywhere. But the fact that its a public method makes me wonder whether it would be a good practice to leave it that way. And since this goes several layers within, it feels odd to do this null check at  all layers and throw exception from all methods :/

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. I don't have a unique solution to this but here a few options:

- You can indeed check for null in both functions. It won't slow down the execution and it is not bad practice. But indeed, if you have a cascade of 10 or 20 sub-functions, having so many checks might seem annoying.
- You can leave it there without a check if you are sure it won't be called anywhere else, but that's not always satisfying.
- You can add a method that throws the right exception if the map is null, this way instead of re-writing a check everywhere, you just have to call the same simple method. I would put such a method in one of your exception classes.

  ```
  public static void checkMapNull(Map<String> map){ // throw exception if map is null }
  public static void handle(Map<String> map) { checkMapNull(map); //dostuff }
  ```
- Another interesting pattern consists in using a key to access your methods. I will go through this last one in details since I find it to be a quite interesting way to solve your issue. Start by creating a public class with a package-private constructor in the package that is supposed to handle the map. Then modify your handle method so that it needs a key as parameter: now only classes that can access the static key are able to call the handle method

  ```
  // Key class - first package
  public class Key {
      private Key(){}
      static Key key;
  }

  // Map handler class - second package
  // Only the first package has a key to call handle!
  public void handle(Map<String> map, Key key){ //dostuff }
  ```

In your case I would go for either the third or second option. But the key pattern in java can be extremely useful in some cases as it allows to mock the *friend* behavior from c++.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your thoughts mate. 2nd and 3rd are very interesting solutions indeed. Let's see if anyone else comes up with any thing new :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a public method, then you have an API with a contract.

If the contract is that nulls are handled specially, then you should code that behaviour.

If the contract doesn't specify how nulls are handled, throwing an NPE (either explicitly or naturally), is acceptable (I would chose this option).

If the method should not be called by anyone, change it's visibility (saying "it's not my code" is not a reason not to do this).